# Calculate the total of math.random in javascript and return a value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three variables which store random number generated by math.random(), then i have three other variables which store the addition of these three variables, like this:

```js
var zikT = 0;
            var hamT = 0;
            var musT = 0;
       $("#reset").click(function(){
             var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12 + 1);
            var random_0 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12 + 1);
             var random_1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12 + 1);
           zikT += (random_0);
           hamT += (random);
           musT += (random_1);
              })
```

```html
<p id="leading"></p>
```

My dilemma is that in p the p tag with id leading I want the name of the person who has the highest number I know I can't explain but i want to do something code below does below:

```js
if(zikT > hamT && zikT > musT){
    $("#leading").html('you');
}else if(hamT > zikT && hamT > musT){
            $("#leading").html('me');
        }   
    else if(musT > zikT && musT > hamT){
            $("#leading").html('i');
        }
```

It doesn't work and even if it does it does the wrong calculation.

Comment: the math calculation is wrong or you have problem with html doms??

Comment: It doesn't print out the value that's actually at the top and even if it does it once i want it so everytime an expression changes the inner html of <p id="leading"></p> changes too.

Comment: Also where is the case when `zikt==hamt==must` or `zikt==hamt` or `hamt==must` etc. Its random dosnt mean it will always be unique.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Math.max()` and find which is the highest one.

```
var highest = Math.max(zikT , hamT, musT);
```

**Update**

then use `if else` to find name to display

```
if(highest == zikT){
     $("#leading").html('you');
}else if(highest == hamT){
     $("#leading").html('me');
}else if(highest == musT){
     $("#leading").html('i');
    }
```

Comment: this display the numeric values of these variables is there a way I can display different names according to the highest value.

Comment: I tried this bro it has fault in it. It did give me an idea to solve the problem tho because it would sometime display the name which is not even the highest it's weird.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
var zikT = 0;
var hamT = 0;
var musT = 0;

$("#reset").click(function(){
        var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12 + 1);
        var random_0 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12 + 1);
        var random_1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12 + 1);
        zikT += random_0;
        hamT += random;
        musT += random_1;
        whoishighest();
});

function whoishighest(){
     if(zikT >= hamT && zikT >= musT){
       //
     }else if(hamT >= zikT && hamT >= musT){
             //
            }else if(musT >= zikT && musT >= hamT){
                     //
                   }  
}
```

Comment: It almost works but it's not accurate there is time when a total number of push up value is 90 and it would still go on and display the other person name whose value is not even the highest.

Answer (score -1):

```
   $("#reset").click(function(){
         var zikT = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12 + 1);
        var hamT = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12 + 1);
         var musT = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12 + 1);

          //DO YOUR LOGIC HERE


          })
```

Comment: what is the reason behind this could you explain?

Comment: You said you wanted to compare 3 people and see who has the highest random number. You set the 3 people with random numbers. Once you have the 3 numbers, start comparing the people numbers with a simple if & else. Set the leading p tag with a document.getElementByID("leading").value = HIghest_Number_Variable

Comment: @wrangler I am trying to make this little pushups exercise application where push ups are generated by math.random for different people. and then total number of is stored in a variable as you can see above and at last

Comment: at last i wanted to show the name of the person who at the moment did more push up in that p tag with leading id.